# How to get a horizontal bar that fills out the remaining space?

Tags: php, html, css

I want it like this:

[image: Reference]

So that the #header-nav is a horizontal bar which has the links(#nav-bar) and that the #bar fills out the remaining space but doesn't wrap to the next row or go behind the links. So it would be like one of the links but extends as far as the #header-nav allows.

The HTML:

```
<div id="header-nav">
    <div id="nav-bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="link1">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="link2">Page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link3">Page2</a></li>
                <li><a href="link4">Page3</a></li>
                <li><a href="link5">Page4</a></li>      
            </ul>
    </div>
<div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#header-nav ul
{
padding-left:0px;
margin: 0;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
list-style-type:none;
text-align: left;
float:center;
margin-top:0px;
}
#header-nav ul li 
{ 
margin-left:1px;
display: inline;
}

#header-nav ul li a
{
text-decoration:none;
padding: .2em .4em;
color: black;
border:1px solid lightgrey;
background-color:lightgrey;
}
```

Comment: [Read this first](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AimqEz What to do you want to know?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify what I needed. I will be updating the question as I get a reference image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My brother found out a solution.

Heres the link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AimqEz/mdaLvza1/)

The CSS:

```
<body>
    <div id="header-nav">

        <div id="cell1">
        <div id="buttons">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="page1">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2">Page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="page3">Page2</a></li>
                <li><a href="page4">Page3</a></li>
                <li><a href="page5">Page4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="cell2">
            <div id="bar">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

The HTML:

```
#buttons ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    color: black;
    border:1px solid lightgrey;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}

#buttons ul {
    padding-left:0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: left;
}

#buttons ul li { 
    margin-left:1px;
    display: inline;
}


#header-nav {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

#cell1 {
    display:table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#buttons {
    float:left;
}

#cell2 {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
    padding: 4px 3px 5px 4px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#bar {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    height:29px;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up display: flex, flex: auto and flex: none. Combined with width: 100% for the container, that should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: #header-nav {display: flex; width: 100%}
#nav-bar {flex: none}
#bar {flex: auto}
?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me your css? Check this out :

http://jsfiddle.net/1ds7t19p/1/

```
    #header-nav {
    width:800px;
    background:#ccc;
    height:50px;    
}

#nav-bar ul {
    width:465px;    
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav-bar ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav-bar ul li a{
    padding:10px 25px;
    background:#999;
    height:50px;    
}
#bar {
    float: right;
    height:50px;    
}
```

Comment: I added the CSS. The idea is that the bar would resize when the page is zoomed or I add more links

Comment: then avoid the background color and width in #bar (Code Edited)